# Scala Play: How to inject test Database into Controller for testing

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

A new scala-play project (v2.5.6) starts with tests examples like this one:

```
"HomeController" should {
  "render the index page" in {
    val home = route(app, FakeRequest(GET, "/")).get
    status(home) mustBe OK
  }
}
```

and controller examples like this one, injecting a `Database` with Guice:

```
class DataManagementController @Inject()(db: Database) extends Controller {...}
```

I would like to test this new controller as above, but injecting a test in-memory database instead of the "default". After hours trying I can't manage to have that. I found clues in

- [Testing a Model](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest#Testing-a-model),
- [Override (Guice) bindings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice#Override-bindings)

(and external [posts](http://labs.septeni-technology.jp/scala/play-framework-fakeapplication-considered-harmful/) using a `FakeApplication`, although they are very complicated and I'd prefer to follow the official, current version's docs.)

From that I understood that there is an `implicit app` argument used in `route(app, ...)`, so I tried to override it:

**Attempt 1**: 
(compiles but still uses database "default")

```
class MySpec extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {

  implicit override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .configure(inMemoryDatabase("test").build()

  "DataManagementController" should { ... }
```

**Attempt 2**:
(does not compile: "Cannot resolve symbol 'TestDb'")

```
class MySpec extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {

  val TestDb = Databases.inMemory(name="test")

  implicit override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .overrides(bind[Database].to[TestDb]).build()

  "DataManagementController" should { ... }
```

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be an issue, but you can try:

```
implicit override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .overrides(bind(classOf[Database]).to(classOf[TestDb]).build()
```

instead of

```
implicit override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .overrides(bind[Database].to[TestDb]).build()
```

and/or

```
"" should {
  "" in new App(appBuilder) {
   }
}
```

where `appappBuilder` is `GuiceApplicationBuilder`